# Prove if $m,n\in \omega$ are equinumerous then $m=n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory

I am reading the following proof:
[image]

Why can we assume bijection between $x$ and $n\cup \{n\}$ exists in the end of the first paragraph? Isn't this what we trying to prove? Further, in the last paragraph, why do we need to show $x\cap n=n$? How is this statement related with $x=n\cup \{n\}$? And if we already have $x\subseteq n\cup \{n\}$ and $n\in x$, why cannot we directly deduce $x\cap n = n$?

Comment: The statement trying to be proved is that $x\subseteq n$ and $|x|  = |n|$ imply $x = n$. So the existence of the bijection is one of the hypotheses of the statement. What's trying to be proved is that $x$ and $n$ are identical, not just equinumerous.